# QProcess - running process whose path contain spaces

Tags: windows, qt, command-line, whitespace, qprocess

In my application, I run a detached process from my Local App Data folder. The code below works for most of the cases.

```
void executeApp(const QString &id)
{
    QString program = QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::AppLocalDataLocation);
    program = program + "\\..\\Programs\\MyApp.exe";
    QStringList arguments;
    arguments << "--app_id="+id; //it is only one argument
    QProcess* process = new QProcess(this);
    bool success = process->startDetached(program, arguments);
    if (!success) //TODO: Error handling
        qDebug() << "Couldn't start process at " << program << process->errorString();

}
```

Running some tests, I found out that it doesn't work when the Windows account user name contain spaces in it (Windows actually allows that).

How could that be fixed?

--- edit:

Based on the answers posted, I've changed a little bit the code. However I'm still getting "Unknown Error" on the QMessageBox from the code below:

```
void executeApp(const QString &id)
{
    QString program = QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::AppLocalDataLocation);
    program = QDir(program + "/../Programs/MyApp.exe").absolutePath();
    QStringList arguments;
    arguments << "--app_id="+id; //it is only one argument
    QProcess* process = new QProcess(this);
    bool success = process->startDetached(program, arguments);

    if (!success) 
        QMessageBox::critical(NULL, tr("Launching App"), process->errorString());
}
```

Reinforcing, it only happens when there is an user with one whitespace in the username...

Comment: I've tried using quotes (""), but it didn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[QString QDir::absolutePath() const](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdir.html#absolutePath)

> Returns the absolute path (a path that starts with "/" or with a drive
>   specification), which may contain symbolic links, but never contains
>   redundant ".", ".." or multiple separators.

It makes sense to translate the path from the root to absolute form:

```
QString dataPath = QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::AppLocalDataLocation);
QString exePath = QDir(dataPath + "/../Programs").absolutePath();
qDebug() << "Executable path" << exepath;
qDebug() << "File exists" << QFile(exepath + "/MyApp.exe").exists();
```

As for another concern that it cannot run executable because of spaces in user name included in the path. We should enclose the whole path in quotes so that Windows CreateProcess satisfied:

```
process->startDetached(QStringLiteral("\"") + exepath + "/MyApp.exe" + QChar("\""), arguments);
```

Mind that Qt is usually able to accept both backslash '\' and slash '/' separators for the path argument.

Comment: Good answer for mentioning both "slash" directions to "escape" having to escape each backslash +1

Comment: Thanks for the slash tip. However, I'm still getting "Unknown Error" on process->errorString(), even with QDir, following your code...

Comment: Does exe file exist at the path?

Comment: Yes, it does. It runs as expected if the username doesn't have spaces

Comment: Try to enclose the path in quotes then.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use QDir to resolve paths:

```
QDir dataDir(QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::AppLocalDataLocation));
QString program = dataDir.absolutePath("../Programs/MyApp.exe");
```

Comment: I'm still getting "Unknown Error" on process->errorString(), even with QDir, following your code...